# Linker LNK2005 Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker

I have searched around here and found this question tons of times but the author usually didn't provide a code example, I ran into this problem today and I'm not quite sure how to fix it.

1 of the errors lists `bool Init(?@@A_NA) already defined in Client.obj`. Here is portions of my code for Client.cpp, Main.cpp, and Main.h.

Client.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Main.h"
// the rest of the code doesn't have anything to do with this error..
```

Main.h

```
#include "stdafx.h"
bool Init;
// the rest of the code doesn't have anything to do with this error..
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Main.h"

int main()
{
    Init = false;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `#include "Main.h"` you have defined `bool Init;`, so every-time you include `Main.h`, you will get `Init` redefined. If you make `Init` static,

```
static bool Init;
```

Here `Init` will have page level scope, and your code should work fine.

Or better, you make `Init` extern in `Math.h`,

```
extern bool Init;
```

Then in .cpp file define it, so that you will have multiple declaration, but one definition.

Comment: Better to have it externed in the header and defined in one cpp file if you must use global variables.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Still, it will interfere with other global `Init`, your approach is correct in general, but OP has Client library which has `Init` already defined.

Comment: I don't see that he is using a library at all.  He clearly has two cpp files and a variable declared in a header which causes a multiple definition error.  If you make it static the error will go away but each cpp file will have a different variable.  If you extern it and define it in one place then both share the same variable.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it. I remember now that I got this error before and by making the variables static it started working. Thanks again :)

Comment: @RetiredNinja Just looking at code can you see which libs are linked? No.

Comment: The question describes his code structure which is two cpp files both including the same header.  If anything you're the the one inferring something that isn't there based on his description.  I expect a "why doesn't changing this variable work in another file" question from him soon.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Where doe **Client.obj** came from then?

Comment: From Client.cpp, the first file listed in the question.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Oh I missed that.. updating my answer.